# Show offset of StripLine as a label on the Y-Axis

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have this chart in my WinForms application:

[image]

and I need to show the reference number of the red line (in this case "37")

When I tried to add a CustomLabel to the Y Axis, all the other numbers disappeared.

I tried changing the RowIndex of the label to 2, but here's the result:

[image]

it only shows an inverted "3" instead of a straight "37"

Here's what I need:

[image]

how can I do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: And besides, they're not "C# Charts", they are .NET Windows Forms charts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`TextAnnotation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.textannotation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to show a data value :

[image]

```
  ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
  TextAnnotation ta = new TextAnnotation();

  DataPoint dp0 = Series2.Points[0];  // pick a datapoint!
  ta.Text = dp0.YValues[0] + "";
  ta.ForeColor = dp0.Color;

  ta.AxisY = ca.AxisY;
  ta.Y = dp0.YValues[0];
  ta.X = 5;  // pick a value that fits with your y-axis!

  ta.Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
  chart1.Annotations.Add(ta);
```